# Dynamically loaded assembly in Silverlight calles DllImprot which locks the file

Tags: c#, c++, silverlight

I've quite specific problem with my Silvelight 5 application:
I've application which dynamically loads Silverlight libraries (could be many) and those libraries are callings methods via dllimport.

The reason: application for different scanning devices. Silverlight library is for logic, C++ library is from producer and connects with device. Could be many silverlight libraries and they must be load in runtime.

Problem: after loading Silverlight library and scanning - I can't access file with C++ library. Why I must ? If user tries to pick scanner, I calculate hash code of library to check if there's newer version on the server.

My implementation:
ViewModel is calling method to get current scanner class:

```
 using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(scanner.DirectoryName + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + scanner.ScannerLibraryName, System.IO.FileMode.Open, store))
    {
      AssemblyPart assemblyPart = new AssemblyPart();
      Assembly assembly = assemblyPart.Load(stream);
      return (Scanner)assembly.CreateInstance(scanner.ClassName);
    }
```

Later there's scanning:

```
        this.userScanner.LoadProducerLibrary();
        result = userScanner.ScanDocument();
        this.userScanner.FreeProducerLibrary();
```

LoadProducerLibrary calls:

```
[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);
```

ScanDocument calls some third part methods also via dllimport.

FreeProducerLibray calls:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] /* unnecessary, isn't it? */
public static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);
```

After that, I've a method in different viewmodel which tries to open producer library file to calculate hash code and I get "Cannot access the file, because it is being used by another process".

I've tried to calculate hash code in Scanner class (dynamically load assembly) and it was all right so I suspect it is this process. But why FreeLibrary is not enough ?

Could You point me with some advises ? Should I try to dispose somehow userScanner field ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ScanDocument calls some third part methods also via dllimport.

You left the most important code out of the question, but that statement is enough to diagnose your problem.  The pinvoke marshaller also calls LoadLibrary() on the DLL.  So the reference count for the DLL is *two*.  Your FreeLibrary() call does **not** unload it and the file stays locked.

You can hack around that by calling FreeLibrary() one more time.  That *will* unload the DLL but that also arms a time-bomb in your program.  You cannot safely make these calls again.  The pinvoke marshaller is still convinced that the DLL is loaded so it will not re-generate the stubs that it generated for the imported functions.  They point to the addresses where the functions used to be loaded, not where they are loaded now.  It will *seem* to work, particularly when you do this in an artificial test.  But sooner or later, the DLL cannot get reloaded at the same address again because the address space for it was used for something else and your program will fail with a hard crash.

If you want to make this work then you cannot use [DllImport] for these methods.  You must instead do the work that the pinvoke marshaller does and call GetProcAddress() for every entrypoint you use and make it callable with Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(), using delegates you declared that match the native function signature.  Works, it is not pretty.

The better alternative is to use a separate helper process that makes these calls and interop with it.  Now it is safe, letting that helper process terminate ensures that the pinvoke stubs are gone and the DLL is unlocked.  Not sure what's practical in Silverlight, it wasn't really designed with process interop high on the feature list.  No Process class, that puts a chink in the approach.

Comment: thank You for this brilliant answer. I'll try Your solutions than share it here if I succeed.